# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc!

Tags: errors, packages, input-encodings

I'm getting this problem and I can't find a fix for it. Tried searching but still couldn't find a solution. Here's how the file begins:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
```

I've added the first 3 "usepackages" because I'm writing in portuguese and need the "´~`" symbols and I keep getting the "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc".

How can I fix this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: you have input inputenc twice with different options, just don't do that. Either your file is in utf8 or the legacy apple encoding, it can not be in both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I removed the apple usepackage, but now I'm getting this "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX."

Comment: For portability, you should stick to `utf8` anyway. But don't forget to configure your editor accordingly, for the last problem. Perhaps, also, you now have a mix of both encodings.

Comment: Either you are using a character that is not set up by default or, most likely your file is not in utf-8 encoding. make sure your editor is saving the file in utf-8

Comment: I'm using TeXshop and I'm selecting utf8, but for some reason it keeps in macosroman.. Do you guys know any good editor for this?

Comment: TeXShop is configured for use always MacOS Roman, you should change it in the settings of the editor. I preffer to use TeXstudio, but since it's an app from outside the Applestore is not so easy to install.

Comment: Finally I have utf8 as file encoder (using TexPad), but "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX." error is still here. Any other thoughts on how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Got it! Thanks aradnix, I downloaded texstudio, used xelatex and it finally worked!

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue (for Portuguese language) and solved as follows:

1. The reported issue occurred to me only when a non-Latin character
   appeared in an input TeX file (e.g., chapter1.tex, chapter2.tex,
   etc.) called in main TeX file (e.g., thesis.tex). Note that for the
   main TeX file the package `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` was working
   properly;
2. It must be mentioned that I'm using WinEdt 9.0 editor;
3. So, I set the "document mode" of main file (e.g., thesis.tex) as "TeX" and
   its "Document Format" as "ANSI - 0 Default ANSI code page";
4. Similarly, I set the "document mode" of auxiliary files (e.g.,
   chapter1.tex, chapter2.tex, etc.) as "TeX" and their "Document
   Format" as "ANSI - 0 Default ANSI code page".

In summary: before, each file was configured in different input modes. So, MikTex was unable to compile all them with "latin1" codification. Standardize all files to TeX and ANSI and call the `inputenc` package just once.